# siempre hay que pasar las variables de angular por el HTML?

Tags: angular, typescript, herencia, decoradores

Estoy aprendiendo [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) y me pasa lo siguiente:

Tengo un padre y un hijo, el padre y el hijo tienen que compartir la misma variable para operar. Yo soy capaz de actualizar desde `@Input`
y `@Output` y funciona perfectamente. Pero lo que no me gusta es tener que pasar las variables por `HTML`.

Eso que hice es correcto?

¿Existe otra forma de pasar variables sin usar el `HTML`?

## ESTE ES EL PADRE

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-padre',
  template: `
    <app-hijo 
      [usrBannedList]="usrBannedList"
      [bannedUserIds]="bannedUserIds"
      (usrBannedListChange)="actualizarUsrBannedList($event)"
      (bannedUserIdsChange)="actualizarBannedUserIds($event)">
    </app-hijo>
  `
})
export class PadreComponent {
  usrBannedList?: UserEntity[];
  bannedUserIds?: string[];

  // Método para actualizar usrBannedList
  actualizarUsrBannedList(nuevoValor: UserEntity[]) {
    this.usrBannedList = nuevoValor;
  }

  // Método para actualizar bannedUserIds
  actualizarBannedUserIds(nuevoValor: string[]) {
    this.bannedUserIds = nuevoValor;
  }
}
```

## ESTE ES EL HIJO

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hijo',
  template: `
    <!-- ESTO NO IMPORTA -->
  `
})
export class HijoComponent {
  @Input() usrBannedList?: UserEntity[];
  @Input() bannedUserIds?: string[];
  @Output() usrBannedListChange = new EventEmitter<UserEntity[]>();
  @Output() bannedUserIdsChange = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

  // Método para actualizar usrBannedList
  actualizarUsrBannedList(nuevoValor: UserEntity[]) {
    this.usrBannedListChange.emit(nuevoValor);
  }

  // Método para actualizar bannedUserIds
  actualizarBannedUserIds(nuevoValor: string[]) {
    this.bannedUserIdsChange.emit(nuevoValor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Si sólo el elemento *hijo* va a usar dichas variables o propiedades, no veo el problema de usar `@Input` y `@Output`, sin embargo, cuando debes pasar dichas variables a componentes anidados más profundos, entonces te empiezas a enfrentar al problema de `prop - drilling` o en este caso `Input / Output drilling`. Si ese fuera el caso, existen formas de evitar esto, usando una poderosa herramienta de Angular: el sistema de inyección de dependencias.

Comment: La documentación tiene un apartado que trata de la interacción entre componentes https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction